# How to conect Delphi 10 with NexusDB old version

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, nexusdb

I want to get data from nexusdb 2 to delphi 10. How can i connect delphi 10 to nexus server 2. I can not change nexus server version because another project (Which is developed in Delphi 6) using same database with nexus server 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "Delphi 10" you mean one of the Delphi Seattle, Berlin or Tokyo versions? NexusDB version 2 only supported Delphi 2007 and older versions directly. Because of the unicode change in D2009, trying to update NX2 to work with newer IDEs would be a huge and risky undertaking.

There are some other alternatives, however. If the v2 NX server is a standard one that we supplied, it is quite likely that you will be able to use a newer NX server version, because in general, older clients *can* connect to newer servers and use the databases without problems. You can test this with the latest NexusDB trial version.